# Como dar forma a un dataframe y pasarlo de html a pdf

Tags: html, python, pandas, dataframe, pdf

Creé un programa para stock de artículos e hice una función para convertir el dataframe en una tabla en formato html y luego pasarla a pdf para poder imprimirla, quiero saber como puedo mejorar la estética de la tabla ya que es muy plana y no muy agradable a la vista.

Además, cuando el documento pdf tiene mas de una página, se ve así:
[image: superposición de elementos]
como se observa, los nombres de las columnas se superponen con el primer elemento y quisiera evitar esto. Adjunto el código que genera los archivos

```
def print_data(): #Genera un pdf de la tabla stats

    datos = ordenar_df()
    indices = ["Código", "Nombre", "Cantidad", "Ingresos", "Salidas", "Estado"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns = indices)
    html = df.to_html()
    text_file = open("stock.html", "w")
    text_file.write(html)
    text_file.close()
    pdf_r = 'Stock.pdf'
    pdfk.from_file('stock.html', pdf_r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que no se solapen los titulos podes ajustar al layout del dataframe especificando `index=false` al llamar al método `to_html()`.

También podes intentar incrementar el ancho de las columnas del dataframe especificando las columnas al llamar al método `to_html()`

Ejemplo:

```
html = df.to_html(index=False, columns={"Código": "20%", "Nombre": "40%", "Cantidad": "10%", "Ingresos": "10%", "Salidas": "10%", "Estado": "20%"})
```

Y si queres cambiar la apariencia podrias usar la librería [pandas-style](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html)